# How to tell spring to search sessions in another mongo databaseName than the Default DB instance?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-session

I'm attempting to secure my Resource Server (API SERVER) using spring security and spring session.

Currently I do have two applications. The application **(A)** is a UI application which is secured with Spring security as well and at the same time is a reverse proxy application. The application **(B)** is my API and I want to secure it using session tokens provided by application **(A)** in each REST request through headers.

the architecture is pretty much like this:

[image]

So basically, the UI application do the logins with the users in the **database 2** and creates a session for the logged in user and it works perfect.

Now when I do a REST request (e.g. GET /api/groups) to the API I need to send the session token through headers and the API takes that token and contrast it in the **database 2.**

My problem is that I have configured a default mongo instance through application.properties in my API (spring boot application) and the spring session searches for sessions in that database (**database 1**) not in the **database 2**.

Any Ideas how to tell spring to keep doing API operations in repositories bounded to **database1** and do authentication in **database2**?

I'm using **spring boot 1.5.2 REALEASE**, this is how my POM.XML looks like (dependencies used for security in API):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongo</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

According to: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/EnableMongoHttpSession.html

It's necessary to config Mongo, but remember that I have it configured like this in application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbNumber1
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

So if I do something like this: my API will point to the other database!

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoHttpSession
class MongoHttpSessionConfig {

  @Bean
  public MongoOperations mongoOperations() throws UnknownHostException {
      return new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "dbNumber2");
  }
}
```

I don't see how to implement my custom `MongoHttpSessionConfiguration` or `MongoOperationsSessionRepository` in order to tell spring to just point to the **database2** JUST FOR AUTHENTICATION.

Thank you very much!